# Obtaining the Fredholm alternative kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I am reading through Greenberg's *Foundations of Applied Mathemtics*, and I am having an issue understanding the Fredholm's Alternative.
Consider the initial value problem
$$x'' + 3x = 6t, x(0)=x'(0)=0$$
Integrating from $0$ to $t$ and using the condition $x'(0)=0$, we obtain
$$x'(t) + 3\int_{0}^t x(\tau) d\tau = 3t^2$$
Integrating from $0$ to $t$ and using the condition $x(0)=0$, we obtain
$$x(t) = t^3 - 3\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t'} x(\tau) d\tau dt'$$
Now, the book makes a leap I don't understand. Greenberg says "inverting the order of integration and integrating on $t'$",
$$x(t)= t^3 + 3\int_{0}^t (\tau - t)x(\tau) d\tau$$
How did they get the $(\tau - t)$ term in the integrand? Shouldn't it become
$$x(t)= t^3 + 3\int_{0}^t t'x(\tau) d\tau$$
Why is $t' = \tau -t$, if it even is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture with the $x$-axis being $\tau$ and the $y$-axis being $t'$. Draw the line $t'=\tau$. You should find that the integrating region is the upper right triangle above the line $t'=\tau$. If you switch the integrating order, you are still integrating over this triangle. But it should be obvious that the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^t\int_{\tau}^tx(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}t'\mathrm{d}\tau=\int_0^t x(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau\int_{\tau}^t\,\mathrm{d}t'=\int_0^t x(\tau)(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau.
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer!